# What are the Capitalization Rules for Flowers in Scientific Writing?

Tags: capitalization

I am editing a scientific writing piece that talks about a certain flower. The flower talked about in the writing is mostly not called by its scientific name (the flower is called Butterfly Pea Flower, but its scientific name is *Clitoria ternatea*). I have looked at sources about capitalization rules for flowers, however I have not found any educational domains (.edu) websites, and am not sure if the ones I have found are reliable.

I would also like to know if the rules for American English and British English are the same for when talking about flower capitalization rules. (Sorry if these are very specific questions)

Comment: Google scholar has many papers on the butterfly pea - https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=butterfly+pea+flowers&oq=Butterfly+Pea+Flower. The rules around Latin names are readily available: https://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/writing/HTWlatin.html. The guidance does not apply merely to plants but to all other organisms.

Comment: Common names of plants (as well as other organisms, as @Greybeard points out) are normally lowercase: rose, huckleberry, etc. Whether the plant flowers or not, and whether it includes the word "flower" in its name, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Ok, that answers the question Greybeard, and MarcInManhattan. How do I close the question as it has been answered?

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and then accept it: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. That way the answer will be documented for anyone who finds this question in the future.

Comment: There are many lists. Here is a list of the _county flowers of the United Kingdom_ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_flowers_of_the_United_Kingdom). It includes bee orchid, Maltese-cross, Chiltern gentian, grass-of-Parnassus ... you get the idea. There might have been more of a problem trying to label Alpine catchfly, but the capital A is standard.

Comment: Wikipedia has a fairly lengthy style guide covering this question in considerable detail - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Organisms

Comment: From the above link - "When the common name and part of the scientific name of an organism coincide, do not italicize, and do not capitalize (unless a proper name occurs), except in the context of taxonomy. Examples: The genus Asparagus provides not only the common vegetable asparagus (or garden asparagus), but a number of common ornamental plants including *Asparagus plumosus* (climbing asparagus) ...; and: The caracal (*Caracal caracal*) is also known misleadingly as the "desert lynx", but is not closely related to genus Lynx."

Comment: Again from wiki - Previously, some editors had arrived at a "local consensus" to propose, based on current and historic usage among those who study certain taxa, that the common names of species should be capitalized (generally or just in those categories). Various WikiProjects entirely or mostly capitalized these names in certain categories (e.g. birds, dragonflies, even cetaceans and primates). After numerous consensus discussions in multiple forums, the Wikipedia community rejected this practice as unencyclopedic jargon usage. <cont>

Comment: The Manual of Style thus specifically deprecates this practice. Wikipedia consistently uses lower-case vernacular names regardless of taxonomic category, based on prevailing use in broad, peer-reviewed scientific and academic journals, general-audience mainstream sources, and the recommendations of most English writing authorities, despite the preference for capitalization in some specialist publications.[h]

Comment: My question is too specific. Maybe it should be changed to organisms as flowers fall under it, and organisms follow the same rule. Questioning the capitalization rules for organisms will reach more people (possibly answering their question) about the capitalization rules that follow with it. Not sure if I should change it though (even though I do not see anything wrong with it as there are no duplicate questions to my findings).

Comment: The answers are superficial, although largely correct.  None is based on a search of botanical literature or conventions. References to the Latin binomials and genera are irrelevant to your question, which is about common names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common names of plants (and all other organisms) are **normally lowercase**. Usage of flowers in lowercase (in this case, butterfly pea flowers) can be found in existing Google Scholar scientific writing papers by using its search feature (in this case: [scholar.google.com/…](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=butterfly%20pea%20flowers&oq=Butterfly%20Pea%20Flower)).

Rules around Latin names can be found here: [https://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/writing/…](https://abacus.bates.edu/%7Eganderso/biology/resources/writing/HTWlatin.html).

Credits to @Greybeard and @MarcInManhattan for coming up with the answer.